# Nested element creation not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to create an element within an element. Here it is an img within an anchor tag.
I'm using append child but the "userLogoElement" when logged out is just the img tag and anchor is an empty anchor tag. Why isn't anything happening?

```
         var anchor  = document.createElement('a');
         anchor.href = var0;

         //---- Create image element ----
         var img   = document.createElement('img');
         img.src   = var1;
         img.title = var2;

         //---- Combine elements ----
         var userLogoElement = anchor.appendChild(img);

         console.log(userLogoElement, anchor, img);
         //console says img === userLogoElement, anchor is empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/gcamP/

Be aware [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) returns a reference to the node that was appended, not the node that you appended to. This is why `userLogoElement` is the image not the anchor.

Also note: in Firebug the log only shows the parent anchor, it doesn't include its children in the console log. Chrome on the other hand does show it. An easy way to test is to append it to the document and see for yourself (like in the fiddle).

Comment: That's a weird thing for appendChild to return IMO...I had to use anchor instead of userLogoElement in `findElement(whatever).html(anchor)`

Comment: You could argue it would be better to return the node then you can do method chaining.

Comment: Good point! My original assumptions of how it worked affected how I named and passed the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var0="www.google.com";
var1="bee.jpg";
var2="Don Bee";
    var anchor  = document.createElement('a');
     anchor.href = var0;

     //---- Create image element ----
     var img   = document.createElement('img');
     img.src   = var1;
     img.title = var2;

     //---- Combine elements ----
     var userLogoElement = anchor.appendChild(img);

     console.log(userLogoElement);
     console.log ("next");
     console.log(anchor);
     console.log("next");
     console.log(img);

     </script>
```

I have the following output

userLogoElement : 
    img src="bee.jpg" title="Don Bee"

anchor  :
    a href="www.google.com" img src="bee.jpg" title="Don Bee" /a

this seems like it works fine. The returned value for userLogoElement is not your anchor

Answer (score 0):

```
in jquery short coding style

$("<a>")
.attr('href','www.pranaysonisoft.blogspot.com')
.append($('<img>').attr('src','sdf.jpg'));
```